# Will the run environment variables in Qt Creator use the values on the target machine?

Tags: qt, environment-variables

This might be a naive question, but I currently have the "run" environmental variables in Qt Creator set to include variables like HOME=/home/myusername. When I build the Qt project on my local machine and then distribute to other machines, will these environmental variables take on the values of the target machine or could my environmental variables possibly still be visible to them? Specifically, I'm dynamically linking to the Qt libraries, so theoretically could someone rebuild the Qt libraries and have them print all of the enviromental variables and see the value of HOME on my machine?

I read the QT docs on the run environment, but it wasn't clear. https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-run-settings.html#selecting-the-run-environment

Comment: No, environment variables are specific only to your environment (i.e. your computer).

Answer (score 0):

To read the environment variables at runtime, use the [qgetenv](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qgetenv) global function.